# Tomcat 7 context parameter override

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration

I am trying to override a parameter in my application's web.xml file by creating a context.xml file in `<tomcatHome>/conf/Catalina/localhost`

The context.xml file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myapp">    
    <Parameter name="port" value="100" override="1"/>
</Context>
```

but I get an error saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base <path-to-tomcat> apache-tomcat-7.0.35/webapps/context does not exist or is not a readable directory
```

If I put the `<Parameter name="port" value="100" override="1"/>` directly in the `context.xml` in `<tomcat-home>/context.xml` then it works.

Can someon explain what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because there is no such application context with the name *context*. In other words there is no web app with the name *context* deployed to the *webapps* directory.

Form the official Tomcat 7 documentation related to [Defining a context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context):

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> - In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute)
>     this may be copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and
>     renamed to application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.
> - In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. **The context
>     path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the
>     file name less the .xml extension)**. This file will always take
>     precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's
>     META-INF directory.
> - Inside a Host element in the main conf/server.xml.

So to make it work, name your custom file not *context.xml*, but *your_app_name.xml*.
In your case it will be (if I understood you correctly) ***myapp.xml***.

This should work. I have just tested it.

*myapp.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>    
    <Parameter name="port" value="100" override="1"/>
</Context>
```

---

P.S.

And you can get without *path* attribute, so don't include it.
From the [Apache Tomcat 7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes):

> **This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in
>   server.xml**. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from
>   the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.
>
> **Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute
>   must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false**. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.