# How to specify different context path in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

I already read a number of related questions, but i did not get to a solution for my situation.

I have a webapp in a war-file that includes the version number. E.g.,sourceWarName.war. I cannot use remote deployment, the war file will be deployed manually over the tomcat manager web-interface. I would like the webapp to be accessible over a static path (decoupled from the version), e.g, http://someserver:8080/targetPath
As specified in [tomcat docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696601/tomcat-7-context-parameter-override) and [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696601/tomcat-7-context-parameter-override), it is possible to create a context.xml in my application's META-INF folder like this:

```
<Context path="targetPath" debug="0" reloadable="true">
...
</Context>
```

The file is then supposed to be copied to /tomcat7/conf/Cataline/localhost/sourceWarName-1.0.0.xml. This does not work, however. No xml file is copied. I configured the host-entry in the server.xml to make sure we do not run into double-deployment like this:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartUp="false" copyXml="true">
```

The app, however, is still reachable under /sourceWarName-1.0.0.
What did i miss?

I tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0), but this did not work out for me. Only difference seems to be the docBase.
Tomcat doc says about docBase:

> The value of this field must not be set unless the Context element is
>   defined in server.xml or the docBase is not located under the Host's
>   appBase.

I do not have a context element in server.xml and the appBase is the same.
Running Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu).

Comment: possible duplicate of [HOWTO set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0)

Comment: I tried that solution, but it did not work for me. I added some information to my question